# Exporting R model to OpenCV's Machine Learning Library

Tags: machine-learning, r, open-source

I'm wonder if it's possible to export a model trained in R, to OpenCV's Machine Learning (ML) library format? The latter appears to save/read models in [XML/YAML](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#cvstatmodel-load), whereas the former might be exportable via [PMML](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmml/index.html). Specifically, I'm working with Random Forests, which are classifiers available both in R and OpenCV's ML library.

Any advice on how I can get the two to share models would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Writing a conversion script seems the most straightforward way to do this.

Comment: @AmirAliAkbari - Have you done something like that with R and OpenCV? If so, can you provide an example in the form of an answer? If not, can you point out some promising approaches for writing such a conversion script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *exporting* your models, consider creating an R-based **interoperable environment** for your *modeling* needs. Such environment would consists of *R environment* proper as well as *integration layers* for your third-party libraries. In particular, for the *OpenCV* project, consider either using `r-opencv` open source project (https://code.google.com/p/r-opencv), or integration via *OpenCV* C++ APIs and *R* `Rcpp` package (http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html). Finally, if you want to add *PMML* support to the mix and create a **deployable-to-cloud solution**, take a look at the following excellent blog post with relevant examples: http://things-about-r.tumblr.com/post/37861967022/predictive-modeling-using-r-and-the.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks as if `r-opencv` is relatively unmaintained (last updates 9 months ago, followed by 5 years ago). The PMML option and associated link appear to be great resources. Thanks!

Comment: I see. Well, depending on how you look at it, this might be an opportunity to revive the project (of course, if you're interested and can devote some time to it). I'm glad the other information is helpful to you. Thanks for accepting the answer, which you can also upvote, if you feel generous today :-). Good luck with your project! And keep an eye on [Azure Machine Learning](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning), which I haven't included in my answer, as I consider this offering currently 1) still too raw; 2) not cost-effective; 3) not flexible enough (vs. pure R-based).